# How to sort a list of list of objects by an object's attribute in python

Tags: python, django

I have a list of list of object:

```
[
[obj1, obj2, obj3],
[obj4, obj5, obj6], ...
]
```

object is an instance (returned from a django's queryset) that has a date. Now I want to order the outter list depending on the newest date of each object's list (since each list can have one ore more object, I want to get the newest date as a representation of the whole collection).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the objects are of type `dict` and has a comparable key named *date*:

```
sorted_list = sorted(l, key=lambda items: max(map(itemgetter('date'), items)))
```

A full example with the input generation:

```
from datetime import datetime
from operator import itemgetter

N = 3
M = 4

l = []
for i in range(N):
    l.append([])
    for j in range(M):
        l[-1].append({'date': datetime.now()})

sorted_list = sorted(l, key=lambda items: max(map(itemgetter('date'), items)))
```

If we set `M = N = 2`, this will result:

```
[
   [{'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 28, 13, 14, 15, 172018)}, 
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 28, 13, 14, 15, 172052)}],

   [{'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 28, 13, 14, 15, 172062)},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 28, 13, 14, 15, 172068)}]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each object has a `date` attribute that is of type `datetime.date`

```
def sort_by_date(object_lists):
    def max_date(objects):
        return max(objects, key=lambda obj : obj.date ).date
    return sorted(object_lists, key=max_date, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

in class Meta 
use   ordering  atribute
for example

```
class News(models.Model):
     news_titles = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
     news_preview = models.CharField(max_length=200, , unique=True)
     news_icon = FileBrowseField(u'News icon', max_length=200, directory="IconImages/",
                                     extensions=[".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif"],
                                     blank=True,null=True)
     enabled = models.BooleanField(default=1)
     news_pub_time =  models.DateTimeField(_("Published from"),
         help_text=_("With Published chosen, won't be shown until this time"),
         blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
     news_full_text = models.TextField(max_length=10000,verbose_name=u'Full text')

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.news_titles

     class Meta:
         ordering = ["-news_pub_time"]
         verbose_name = u'News'
```